# error C3860: template argument list

Tags: c++

On my project i designed two template classes:

```
template <size_t n>
LiePoly
{...};
```

and...

```
template <class T, class S, size_t n>
Expression
{...};
// The implementation is not important.
```

In my project I want to use the following class:

```
template<size_t n>
Expression<LiePoly<n>,int,n>
```

(The reason that the "Expression" class is a template class, is because I have another uses to it)

Therefore my question is, how do I combine these two template class? I mean, I want to create a third template class, that uses both.

For example the following is well defined:

```
Expression<LiePoly<7>, int ,7> exp();
```

Thanks for your help!

Hope I am clear enough.

Here is an example for a function that creates the error (This is not the only one but I think it represents)

```
template<size_t n>
void Expression<LiePoly<n>, Symbol,n>::print() const // Here is the error
// "Symbol" is a well defined class
{
    int size = factorial(n - 1) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!N[i]) // N is a member vector of length "size" of integers
            continue;
        if (!C[i].val) // C is a member vector of length "size" of Symbols
        {
            if (N[i] != 1)
                cout << N[i] << "*";
            C[i].print();
            cout << "*";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << N[i] * C[i].val << "*";
        // template<size_t n>
        // Expression<int, Symbol,n> operator * (int k, const Symbol& c)
        // This operator hasn't thrown any error 
        // (maybe this function does because of this...)
        }
        cout << "p_" << V[i].currentNum; 
        // V is a member vector of length "size" of LiePoly<n>
        if (i < size-1 && N[i + 1])
            cout << " + ";
    }
}
```

This is a printing function, in which I think its only problem is with the template. (Because before I instead of n i used a constant integer, and I am now trying to generalise the code).

The problem is in the header of the function, the compiler doesn't recognise the template class. `Expression<LiePoly<n>,int,n>`, and therefore throws the error C3860.

(If needed - I can send the relevant files)

My question is a bit general:

let's assume we have the following classes

```
template<class T>
class A

template<class S>
class B
```

And I want to define the following template

```
template<class R>
B<A<R>>
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Is `Expression<LiePoly<n>, Symbol,n>` not recognized as a valid typename? Please post a minimal example that generates the error, and the compiler output

Comment: What's the error?